# Is it haraam to watch gay porn?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamualaikum I admit I have watched gay porn in the past I have always been gay internally but that's okay I love my Lord and I know that sodomy(homosexuality) is haraam so I wanted to know **is watching gay porn allowed in Islam?**

Answer (score 2):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullahi wabarkatehu,

First if all you should know the story of Prophet Lut AS:
"Of all the creatures in the world, will ye approach males, And leave those whom Allah has created for you to be your mates? Nay, ye are a people transgressing (all limits)!" They said: "If thou desist not, O Lut! thou wilt assuredly be cast out!" He said: "I do detest your doings. O my Lord! deliver me and my family from such things as they do!" So We delivered him and his family,- all Except an old woman who lingered behind. Then afterward We destroyed the others. We rained down on them a shower (of brimstone): and evil was the shower on those who were admonished (but heeded not)!
Qur'an 26:165

And about your question a Hadith:
Narrated AbuSa'id al-Khudri: The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: A man should not look at the private parts of another man, and a woman should not look at the private parts of another woman. A man should not lie with another man without wearing lower garment under one cover; and a woman should not be lie with another woman without wearing lower garment under one cover. 
Abu Dawud 31:4007

You hould know better why women exist (for men in legal ways) and why men exit (for women in ligal ways).
May Allah guide you, As you Lord lover you should dislike what Allah dislikes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Islam puts a definite target in front of human beings i.e. an eternal life in Paradise. The only way to qualify for it is moral purification:

> He who purifies it will indeed be successful, and he who corrupts it
>   is sure to fail. [91:10](http://tanzil.net/#91:10)

All the injunctions of the Qur'an relate to this aim. Abstaining from **الْفَوَاحِش** is no different. It hinders your moral purification. That is why the Qur'an has explicitly forbidden any act that comes under this:

> and that ye draw not nigh to **lewd** things whether open or concealed [6:151](http://tanzil.net/#6:151)

The case under discussion definitely comes under concealed lewd things. It is great that you have get rid of it!

It can definitely be difficult to get rid of a bad habit one has developed. Every time one succumbs to such an act he should repent, seek forgiveness from God and ask for His help in overcoming such habits.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,all praises and thanks are due to Allah who made us muslims and gave us this beautiful religion （i.e, Islam）.

And regarding the answer to this question , First of all ,you should know that while watching this porn you are committing lesser kind of of fornication which may lead you to a major sin as well as decreasing of your iman as the Prophet Muhammad （p.b.u.h）said

لا يزني الزاني حين يزني و هو مؤمن

And we as muslims should protect ourselves from committing any kind of zina whether it is the minor one or not .In short , watching porn movies is haraam and may Allah protect us from that and Allah knows best .

غفر اللّٰه لنا جميعا وذكّرنا مما نسينا والسلام عليكم ورحمة اللّٰه وبركاته